# This code uses only one array `dist`, but works correctly. Why? (Floyd–Warshall Algorithm)

Tags: algorithm, floyd-warshall

The following code is a python code for Floyd–Warshall Algorithm.
After this code terminates, `dist[x][y]` is the shortest distance from the node `x` to the node `y`.

```
for i in range(N):
  dist[i][i] = 0

for k in range(N):
  for x in range(N):
    for y in range(N):
      dist[x][y] = min(dist[x][y], dist[x][k] + dist[k][y])
```

The above code uses only one array `dist`, but works correctly.
We don't need to modify the above code as follows:

```
for i in range(N):
  dist[i][i] = 0

for k in range(N):
  for x in range(N):
    for y in range(N):
      next_dist[x][y] = min(dist[x][y], dist[x][k] + dist[k][y])
  for x in range(N):
    for y in range(N):
      dist[x][y] = next_dist[x][y]
```

Why?